# Remove All Nodes with (nodeName = "script") from a Document Fragment *before placing it in dom*

Tags: javascript, append, fragment

My goal is to remove all <[script]> nodes from a document fragment (leaving the rest of the fragment intact) before inserting the fragment into the dom.

My fragment is created by and looks something like this:

```
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0));
    documentFragment = range.cloneContents();
    sasDom.insertBefore(documentFragment, credit);
    document.body.appendChild(documentFragment);
```

I got good range walker suggestions in a separate post, but realized I asked the wrong question. I got an answer about ranges, but what I meant to ask about was a document fragment (or perhaps there's a way to set a range of the fragment? hrmmm). The walker provided was:

```
function actOnElementsInRange(range, func) {
function isContainedInRange(el, range) {
    var elRange = range.cloneRange();
    elRange.selectNode(el);
    return range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, elRange) <= 0
            && range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, elRange) >= 0;
}

var rangeStartElement = range.startContainer;
if (rangeStartElement.nodeType == 3) {
    rangeStartElement = rangeStartElement.parentNode;
}

var rangeEndElement = range.endContainer;
if (rangeEndElement.nodeType == 3) {
    rangeEndElement = rangeEndElement.parentNode;
}

var isInRange = function(el) {
    return (el === rangeStartElement || el === rangeEndElement ||
                isContainedInRange(el, range))
        ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
};

var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;
if (container.nodeType != 1) {
    container = container.parentNode;
}

var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, isInRange, false);

while (walker.nextNode()) {
    func(walker.currentNode);
}
}

actOnElementsInRange(range, function(el) {
    el.removeAttribute("id");
});
```

That walker code is lifted from: [Remove All id Attributes from nodes in a Range of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690122/remove-all-id-attributes-from-nodes-in-a-range-of-fragment)

*PLEASE* No libraries (ie jQuery). I want to do this the raw way. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to gather all `<script>` nodes would be to use `getElementsByTagName`, but unfortunately that is not implemented on `DocumentFragment`.

However, you could create a temporary container and append all elements within the fragment, and then go through and remove all `<script>` elements, like so:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');

while (documentFragment.firstChild)
    temp.appendChild(documentFragment.firstChild);

var scripts = temp.getElementsByTagName('script');
var length = scripts.length;

while (length--)
    scripts[length].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[length]);

// Add elements back to fragment:
while (temp.firstChild)
    documentFragment.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
```

Comment: When I've appended it to existing dom elements, it's executed the javascript. This crashed the browser. I suspect that will happen again, although maybe it won't because temp isn't placed in the dom yet?

Comment: What if the while loop that did documentFragment.firstChild did a test to see if the nodeName was script, and if so, it didn't append?

Comment: Appending `<script>`s to out-of-DOM elements shouldn't cause any execution.

Comment: You could do the `while(documentFragment.firstChild)` thing, but it'll only catch scripts that are direct children of the fragment... not nested children -- E.g. `[FRAGMENT]<div><script/></div>[/FRAGMENT]`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the documentFragment is a real DOM Fragment, you should be able to do something like:

```
var scripts = documentFragment.getElementsByTagName('script');
if (scripts.length){
  for (var i=0, l = scripts.length;i<l;i++){
    documentFragment.removeChild(scripts[i]);
  }
}
```

right?

Correction: you can't apply getElementsByTagName to a documentFragment, J-P is right. You can however us a child of the fragment if it is a (cloned) node supporting getElementsByTagName. Here's some (working) code I use within a larger script a few days ago:

```
var fragment = d.createDocumentFragment(), f;
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
fragment.firstChild.appendChild(zoeklijst.cloneNode(true));
f = fragment.firstChild;
return f.getElementsByTagName(getList); //<==
```

Comment: Note J-P's response, which notes get by tagname doesn't work on fragments.

Comment: See the corrected answer. The $ is not jquery by the way, I use a home brew javascript framework to wrap DOM elements.

Comment: Should your homebrew javascript framework be included too then? Where does "zoeklijst" come from?

Comment: No, you don't need the framework. See edit: Removed the framework stuff. 'Zoeklijst' is a div containing a lot of p elements.

Answer (score 0):

2022, Chrome, querySelector family works on document fragments:

```
frag.content.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(
    (s)=>s.remove()
    );
```